# Override update method of UpdateAPIView

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to do some actions, before calls update().

**my code**

```
class CarView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = CarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some actions
        super(CarView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I'm getting an error

**error message**

> Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be
>   returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most Django views, your `update` method on the `ViewSet` should be returning a response. Right now you aren't returning anything, which is why Django is complaining about receiving `NoneType` (as that is the default return value).

The issue is coming from the last line of your `update` method, where you are calling the parent `update` but aren't returning it.

```
super(CarView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you returned it, the response that came from the `update` method that is normally defined would be passed down the chain and rendered as you would expect.

```
return super(CarView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have **not returned anything** in your `update` method. Django views expect a `Response` object to be returned. Just add a `return` in your `update` method.

```
class CarView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = CarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some actions
        return super(CarView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

According to docs,

> REST framework supports HTTP content negotiation by providing a
>   Response class which allows you to return content that can be rendered
>   into multiple content types, depending on the client request.
>
> The Response class subclasses Django's SimpleTemplateResponse.
>   Response objects are initialised with data, which should consist of
>   native Python primitives. REST framework then uses standard HTTP
>   content negotiation to determine how it should render the final
>   response content.

So, to render the data into different content types, you have to return a response.